# webkit-scrollbar is not working in chrome

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I have below code in my css file :

```
.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

When I open the page in chrome, it appears that chrome treat these width and background as "invalid property value". I am not sure what is the problem.

[image: Attached screenshot]

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/w8curnom/), you must have some other style overwriting it - that's what the crossed out usually means - keep looking down the list of styles until you find the one that is applied

Comment: i have cross verified it. If there are some css which would have overridden this one then it should not show that yellow warning symbol. Its showing the yellow warning symbol as shown in screenshot.

Comment: @user3247691 can you put all the code applied on `.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper` into a jsfiddle?, this would make it easier to see what happens.

Comment: Also if you hover over the exclamation mark, it usually tells you what the error is

Comment: please check the scrrenshot.

Comment: That must be some third party plugin you are using - have you disabled all your browser plugins.  Also, if you look at my fiddle in the first comment, does that work or not?

Comment: @Pete, yeah your fiddle is working. chrome should not show this invalid property. Its misleading the concept.

Comment: if i run @Pete 's anwser in google chrome, i get this result: `https://imgur.com/a/kIYdu8c`, so there is probably some other code applied to `.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper` that we can't see in the screenshot attached.

Comment: @RamondeVries, If i add the same piece of code by using new style chrome feature, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

but why you didn't go with # (id= ?, anyway try this :

```css
/* width */
.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.1px !important;
}

/* Track */
.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent !important; 
}
 
/* Handle */
.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent !important; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
.workarea-view-scroll-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: transparent !important; 
}
```